# #define func(t, a, b){ t temp; temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}

Tags: c

can any one please tell me how the below code works,

```
#define func(t, a, b){  t temp; temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}

int main()
{

int a=3, b=4;
float c=4.5, d=5.99;

func(int, a, b);
func(float, c, d);

printf("%d %d\n", a,b);
printf("%.2f %.2f\n",c,d);

return 0;
}
```

this will give a swapped output as below

```
4 3
5.99 4.50
```

My questions are

1)is "#define func(" is a function with variable argument..??

2)why is "t temp;" is not giving any error??

3)is it possible to send the data type as an argument.??

I dont know how it is working, i know only sending variables,structures, pointers and values, but i don know how can we send data type and, why is sending a data type is required,

Comment: [Please write a better title to your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title)

Comment: The `#define` directive is for the preprocessor, and creates a *macro* and not a function. And this code have nothing to do with C# so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: To learn more, you might want to run your code through the preprocessor, and look at the code generated. Then you will see what happened and how the compiler will see the code.

Comment: Who in their right mind calls a macro `func`?

Comment: thanks guys, for comments and explanations about macros and above code,..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what kind of "c" is that, but as it seems (if code compiles, runs and produces expected result):

```
#define func(t, a, b){  t temp; temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

`#define` is [pre-processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) directive commonly used to create aliases (macros).
`func(...)` is a *function-like macro name*, what pre-processor will look for in your code and replaces with **what is after that**.

Inside `()` you define *parameters*: `t`, `a` and `b`. Whenever you write `func(1,2,3)` these comma-separated values will be assigned to parameters: `t` will become `1`, `a` = `2` and `b` = `3`. Then *macro body* will be processed to generate inline code with those values. Because this replacement occurs *before compilation* (that is what pre-processing stands for), there are **no checks** or errors, your source will be modified and only then compilation occurs (possibly producing compile-time errors).

When you write `func(int, a, b);` line, then during pre-processing it will be modified into

```
{  t temp; temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

where `t` = `int`, `a` = `a` and `b` = `b` , so it become

```
{  int temp; temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

and then this will be compiled. As you can see it's perfectly valid code.

Specifically to your question, you are not sending types of anything in macros. Macros operate with *plain text* same way as you would type the text to produce source code.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you need to know. First, `t`, `a`, and `b` are all substituted into the body of the macro no matter what they are, THEY ARE NOT VARIABLES!

Thus when you say:

`func(int, a, b)`

it is interpreted as this:

Create a variable called `temp` of type `t` (in this case an int), then set temp equal to the value of a and b equal to the value of temp.

Although it may look it, this macro is NOT A FUNCTION!

The main purpose of a macro is to avoid repetitive coding, although you can also use it to perform interesting type-independent substitution as in this case.